# create multiple table using FMDB Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I installed `FMDB` `cocoapods` to create database in my app (sqlite) but i stuck in a situation while creating more then one table inside the database. I created an extension for that.

Here is my code:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func createTable(table: String){

        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let dirPaths = filemgr.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)

        let databasePath = dirPaths[0].URLByAppendingPathComponent("contacts.db").path!

        if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String){

            let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

            if contactDB == nil {
                print("Error: \(contactDB?.lastErrorMessage())")
            }

            if (contactDB?.open())! {
               let sql_stmt = table
               if !(contactDB?.executeStatements(sql_stmt))! {
                    print("Error: \(contactDB?.lastErrorMessage())")
                }else {
                    print("table created")
                }
                contactDB?.close()
            } else {
                print("Error: \(contactDB?.lastErrorMessage())")
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Calling extension:

```
// calling first time
createTable("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)")

// calling again
reateTable("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DESIGNATION (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, DESIG TEXT)")
```

So when i call extension to create tables it only creates `CONTACTS` table it doesn't create `DESIGNATION` table when i call this second time and so on.

What i am doing wrong here anybody please help inside this. Thanks.

Using Swift2.

Comment: is anybody have experience using fmdb please share your views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by creating a single query statement instead of calling extension again and again to create table.

Here is the query:

```
let tables = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT);" +
             "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DESIGNATION (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, DESIG TEXT);"

// calling extension
createTable(tables)
```

Writing this ans to make useful for other users.
Thanks everyone :)

Comment: This is not working in swift 3, it creates only first table(CONTACTS). Any update?

Comment: check string you are passing `create table statement` or show how you are doing.

Comment: @KarthikeyanSk as provided in question, also make sure you are using     `executeStatements` , and not `executeUpdate`.  This got me stuck for a bit.