# SQLite.swift (Release 0.11.2) sample code is not working

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

I am trying to use [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift#usage) sample code but it is throwing an error.

First step I have done is to install it using cocoapods and it was successful. Then I have tried to test it in my app delegate where I declare import SQLite and I have added the below code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but it is showing an error.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let db = try Connection("path/to/db.sqlite3")

    let users = Table("users")
    let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
    let name = Expression<String?>("name")
    let email = Expression<String>("email")

    try db.run(users.create { t in
        t.column(id, primaryKey: true)
        t.column(name)
        t.column(email, unique: true)
    })

    return true
}
```

The error I am getting from this code line (let db = try Connection("path/to/db.sqlite3")) is **"Errors thrown from here are not handled"**

Is there anyone experiencing the same issue? I am using XCode 8.2.1 and Swift 3.0.

Comment: Have a look at the "Error Handling" chapter in the Swift Reference book: `try` must be called inside a `do {  } catch {  }` environment.

Comment: https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/462.

Comment: Thanks @martin-r, I just copy pasted the code from the github repo guide and assume that it works. I will make the changes and try your suggestion.

Comment: I have posted now a solution above. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Don't post solutions in the question. You can accept an answer if it helped, or post your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @martin-r for the solution. Here's the updated code.
Solution:

```
do {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

        let db = try Connection("\(documentsPath)/db.sqlite3")

        let users = Table("users")
        let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
        let name = Expression<String?>("name")
        let email = Expression<String>("email")

        try db.run(users.create { t in
            t.column(id, primaryKey: true)
            t.column(name)
            t.column(email, unique: true)
        })

    } catch {
        // Handle error
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to know what it should do when there is a runtime error. What you're missing is a `do/catch` clause or the `throws` keyword at your function declaration. For more details have a look at [chapter "Error Handling" of the the Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html).

Comment: miho do you have any view regarding this ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464076/create-multiple-table-using-fmdb-swift ?